# Not able to configure Management Centre in Hazlecast-5.2.1

Tags: hazelcast, hazelcast-cloud

After upgrading the com.hazelcast group to 5.2.1 version, not able to configure the ManagementCentre url. Not able to see the following method itself, do I need to any other alternate config api for this?

ManagementCenterConfig managementCenterConfig = new ManagementCenterConfig();
managementCenterConfig.setUrl(hazelCastConfiguration.getManCenterUrl());

able to config mancenter url in lower version.